# Flask Admin , not able to put filter and can not set search column

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin

I have went through other answers but none of them seems to answer this question , I have cloned [sandman2](https://github.com/jeffknupp/sandman2) which does not have column filter and column searchable option in admin dashboard , below is the ModelView

```
from flask_admin.contrib.sqla import ModelView

class CustomAdminView(ModelView):  # pylint: disable=no-init
    """Define custom templates for each view."""
    list_template = 'list.html'
    create_template = 'create.html'
    edit_template = 'edit.html'
    column_display_pk = True
    ModelView.can_export = True
    ModelView.can_delete = False
    ModelView.can_view_details = True
    ModelView.can_set_page_size = True
    ModelView.can_create = False
    ModelView.page_size = 500
```

And I am calling this in app.py

```
def register_model(cls, admin=None):
    """Register *cls* to be included in the API service

    :param cls: Class deriving from :class:`sandman2.models.Model`
    """
    cls.__url__ = '/{}'.format(cls.__name__.lower())
    service_class = type(
        cls.__name__ + 'Service',
        (Service,),
        {
            '__model__': cls,
        })

    # inspect primary key
    cols = list(cls().__table__.primary_key.columns)

    # composite keys not supported (yet)
    primary_key_type = 'string'
    if len(cols) == 1:
        col_type = cols[0].type
        # types defined at http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#url-route-registrations
        if isinstance(col_type, sqltypes.String):
            primary_key_type = 'string'
        elif isinstance(col_type, sqltypes.Integer):
            primary_key_type = 'int'
        elif isinstance(col_type, sqltypes.Numeric):
            primary_key_type = 'float'

    # registration
    register_service(service_class, primary_key_type)

    if admin is not None:
        columns = (c.name for c in (list(cls().__table__.columns)) if not c.primary_key)
        cv = CustomAdminView(cls, db.session)
        cv.column_filters = columns
        cv.column_searchable_list = list(columns)
        admin.add_view(cv)
```

Still no luck , no filter option on the admin neither the filter option.

Comment: and where is HTML which display filter option?

Comment: {% extends 'admin/model/list.html' %}
This is all in list.html